# Percentage of Cross product purchase

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to determine how many people have purchased a pair of goods out of all distinct pairs of products that can exist. E.g. I have three products, A, B, C and I would like to determine how many % of customers bought A and B, B and C, and A and C out of the number of customers who own either product within each pair by country.

My table looks like the below.

```
 Customer | Country | Product
 1        |    US   |    A
 1        |    US   |    B
 2        |    CA   |    A
 2        |    CA   |    C
 3        |    US   |    A
 3        |    US   |    C
 4        |    US   |    B
 5        |    US   |    A
```

Note that a customer can only belong to one country.

My desired output is:

```
 Country | Pair |   %
 US      | A_B  |  25%    
 US      | B_C  |   0%
 US      | A_C  |  33%
 CA      | A_B  |   0%    
 CA      | B_C  |   0%
 CA      | A_C  | 100%
```

The % is essentially the ratio

```
(# of unique customers who bought Product1 and Product2)/
(# of unique customers who bought Product1 or Product2)
```

by country.

So for instance, in the US for `A_B` we have 4 customers who bought `A` or `B` but only 1 of these bought both `A` and `B` so the ratio is `1/4`.

Is there a nice solution to this which would scale if I had a large number, arbitrary number of pairs?

Comment: Shouldn't the US A_C value be 33%, not 25%?  Three customers (1, 3, 5) bought either A or C, and one of them (3) bought both.

Comment: @APH you're correct. It should be 33%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterative query development...

If you don't have a `product` table, and only have the `customer_country_product` table, you can use an inline view to create a distinct list of products for each country.

To get products by country...

```
  SELECT ccp.product_id
       , ccp.country_id
    FROM customer_country_product ccp
   GROUP
      BY ccp.product_id
       , ccp.country_id
```

We can use that query as a rowsource, by making it an inline view.  Wrap that query in parens, assign an alias, and reference it in the FROM clause of another query. In order to get "pairs" of products, we can join the inline view to itself (avoiding returning pairs of the same product (`A_A`), and avoiding returning "duplicate" pairs (return only one of `A_C` and `C_A`).

```
  SELECT a.country_id
       , a.product_id AS a_product_id
       , b.product_id AS b_product_id
    FROM ( SELECT ccpa.product_id
                , ccpa.country_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpa
            GROUP
               BY ccpa.product_id
                , ccpa.country_id
         ) a 
    JOIN ( SELECT ccpb.product_id
                , ccpb.country_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpb
            GROUP
               BY ccpb.product_id
                , ccpb.country_id
         ) b
      ON b.country_id = a.country_id 
     AND b.product_id > a.product_id
   ORDER
      BY a.country_id
       , a.product_id
       , b.product_id
```

That should get you all the product "pairs" for each country. NOTE: this will omit products that there isn't a customer that has the product.  If we want all possible product pairs, for each country, we'd need to write that a little differently...

```
  SELECT c.country_id
       , a.product_id AS a_product_id
       , b.product_id AS b_product_id
    FROM ( SELECT ccpa.product_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpa
            GROUP BY ccpa.product_id
         ) a 
    JOIN ( SELECT ccpb.product_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpb
            GROUP BY ccpb.product_id
         ) b
      ON b.product_id > a.product_id
   CROSS
    JOIN ( SELECT ccpc.country_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpc
            GROUP BY ccpc.country_id
         ) c
    ORDER
      BY c.country_id
       , a.product_id
       , b.product_id
```

If you have `product` and `country` tables, you could replace the inline views in the queries above with references to those tables.

To get the "counts" of customer, we could either use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list, or we can perform join operations and aggregates in the SELECT list. (With the joins, if we're not careful, there's a potential to generate and count "duplicates".)

To get a count of the distinct customers in a particular country that has a particular product

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ccp.customer_id) AS cnt_cust
  FROM customer_country_product ccp
 WHERE ccp.country_id = ?
   AND ccp.product_id = ?
```

To get a count of distinct customers from a particular country that has at least one of two particular products

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ccp.customer_id) AS cnt_cust_have_either
  FROM customer_country_product ccp
 WHERE ccp.country_id = ?
   AND ccp.product_id IN ( ? , ? )
```

To get a count of customers in a particular country that have two particular products:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ccp1.customer_id) AS cnt_cust_have_both
  FROM customer_country_product ccp1
  JOIN customer_country_product ccp2
    ON ccp2.country_id = ccp1.country_id
   AND ccp2.customer_id = ccp1.customer_id
 WHERE ccp1.country_id = ? 
   AND ccp1.product_id = ?
   AND ccp2.product_id = ?
```

Since those queries return a single row containing a single column, we can use those as expressions in the SELECT list of another query. We start with the "product pairs" query, and add to the SELECT list. We replace those question mark placeholders with references to columns from the outer query:

```
  SELECT c.country_id
       , a.product_id AS a_product_id
       , b.product_id AS b_product_id
       , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ccp1.customer_id)
             FROM customer_country_product ccp1
             JOIN customer_country_product ccp2
               ON ccp2.country_id = ccp1.country_id
              AND ccp2.customer_id = ccp1.customer_id
            WHERE ccp1.country_id = c.country_id
              AND ccp1.product_id = a.product_id
              AND ccp2.product_id = b.product_id
         ) AS cnt_cust_have_both
       , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ccp.customer_id)
             FROM customer_country_product ccp
            WHERE ccp.country_id = c.country_id
              AND ccp.product_id IN (a.product_id,b.product_id)
         ) AS cnt_cust_have_either
    FROM ( SELECT ccpa.product_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpa
            GROUP BY ccpa.product_id
         ) a 
    JOIN ( SELECT ccpb.product_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpb
            GROUP BY ccpb.product_id
         ) b
      ON b.product_id > a.product_id
   CROSS
    JOIN ( SELECT ccpc.country_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpc
            GROUP BY ccpc.country_id
         ) c
    ORDER
      BY c.country_id
       , a.product_id
       , b.product_id
```

Now, to calculate the "percentage" we just need to do a division operation. With MySQL a "divide by zero" will return NULL. (We wouldn't need to be concerned with that, if our outer query only returned rows where we know a customer from the country has one of the products... i.e. the result returned by the first query

```
  SELECT c.country_id
       , a.product_id AS a_product_id
       , b.product_id AS b_product_id
       , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ccp1.customer_id)
             FROM customer_country_product ccp1
             JOIN customer_country_product ccp2
               ON ccp2.country_id = ccp1.country_id
              AND ccp2.customer_id = ccp1.customer_id
            WHERE ccp1.country_id = c.country_id
              AND ccp1.product_id = a.product_id
              AND ccp2.product_id = b.product_id
         )
       / ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ccp.customer_id)
             FROM customer_country_product ccp
            WHERE ccp.country_id = c.country_id
              AND ccp.product_id IN (a.product_id,b.product_id)
         ) 
       * 100.00 AS percent_cust_have_both
    FROM ( SELECT ccpa.product_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpa
            GROUP BY ccpa.product_id
         ) a 
    JOIN ( SELECT ccpb.product_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpb
            GROUP BY ccpb.product_id
         ) b
      ON b.product_id > a.product_id
   CROSS
    JOIN ( SELECT ccpc.country_id
             FROM customer_country_product ccpc
            GROUP BY ccpc.country_id
         ) c
    ORDER
      BY c.country_id
       , a.product_id
       , b.product_id
```

As far as "scaling" that up, for any non-trivial table, we are going to need to have suitable indexes available. Especially for the correlated subqueries. Those are going to get executed for *every* row returned by the outer query.

That last query has the potential to return NULL, when there is a count of zero in the denominator. We can substitute a zero, by wrapping that while division operation in a conditional test

```
 IFNULL( <expr> , 0) * 100.00 AS
```

(Likely there's an error somewhere in those queries, a missing paren, an invalid reference, a wrong qualifier, etc. Those queries are not tested. I strongly recommend you test each one, and not just grabbing that last one.)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

A table for testing...

```
CREATE TABLE customer_country_product
( customer_id INT
, country_id  VARCHAR(2)
, product_id  VARCHAR(2)
)
;
INSERT INTO customer_country_product (customer_id, country_id, product_id) VALUES
 ('1','US','A')
,('1','US','B')
,('2','CA','A')
,('2','CA','C')
,('3','US','A')
,('3','US','C')
,('4','US','B')
,('5','US','A')
;
```

Final query returns:

```
country_id  a_product_id  b_product_id  percent_cust_have_both
----------  ------------  ------------  ----------------------
CA          A             B               0.000000
CA          A             C             100.000000
CA          B             C               0.000000
US          A             B              25.000000
US          A             C              33.333333
US          B             C               0.000000
```

It would a trivial change to concatenate `a.product_id` and `b.product_id` into a single column.  The second and third columns in the SELECT list could be replaced with something like `CONCAT(a.product_id,'_',b.product_id) AS a_b`.

Comment: Whoops. I had MySQL in mind when I wrote this answer, not SQL Server. My bad. Some of the syntax might be specific to MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is exactly what I needed and is really clear.

Comment: @Black: That turned out to be a fairly lengthy query. I tried to demonstrate a step-wise, incremental approach to building that query, testing along the way. (There's no way I could come up with that final query in one fell swoop; I'm just not smart/talented enough to do that.)  For SQL Server, that division operation may throw an error if it's a "divide by zero" operation. I recommend wrapping the denominator expression in a function that returns NULL when it evaluates to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate all pairs of products along with the country.  Then you need to calculate the number of matching customers that purchased either and the number that purchased both.

Let me assume you have a products table and a countries table.  Then, I think that subqueries might be the simplest solution:

```
select p1.product as product1, p2.product as p2,
       (select count(*)
        from (select cp.customer
              from customerproducts cp
              where cp.product in (p1.product, p2.product) and
                    cp.country = c.country
              group by cp.customer
              having count(distinct product) = 2
             ) cp
       ) as numWithBoth,
       (select count(*)
        from (select cp.customer
              from customerproducts cp
              where cp.product in (p1.product, p2.product) and
                    cp.country = c.country
              group by cp.customer
             ) cp
       ) as numWithEither
from countries c cross join
     products p1 cross join
     products p2 ;
```

The final answer is the ratio of the two values.

Comment: This looks pretty good. But doesn't inline view `cp` need a `GROUP BY` clause? Won't the aggregate (`COUNT`) in the `HAVING` clause collapse that to a single row, returning only one customer?  (or throw an error if sql_mode includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`?) Does MySQL limit the depth at which a correlated subquery can reference columns from an outer query? (Maybe that's just in an older version or its a different database I'm thinking of.) Won't this return duplicate pairs, e.g. `A_C` and `C_A`, as well as `A_A` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have this one table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative method using CTEs, and assuming you only have the table you posted (so there's some extra work to extract the country/product combination list).  It is probably possible to do this in fewer steps, but I wanted to spell out the solution so it's easier to see what's happening.

```
drop table #test

create table #test (customer int, country varchar(2), product char(1))
insert into #test values (1, 'US','A')
insert into #test values (1, 'US','B')
insert into #test values (2, 'CA','A')
insert into #test values (2, 'CA','C')
insert into #test values (3, 'US','A')
insert into #test values (3, 'US','C')
insert into #test values (4, 'US','B')
insert into #test values (5, 'US','A')

; with CTE as ( --Count the number of customers ordering each item
    select country, product, count(distinct customer) as TotalOrders
    from #test
    group by country, product
    )
, CTE2 as ( --Join the order counts back to the original data set (can do this in CTE as a windowed function if you don't have customers ordering the same product more than once)
    select a.*, b.TotalOrders from #test a
    left join cte b
    on a.country = b.country and a.product = b.product
    )
, combinations as ( --Generate all possible country/product combinations
    Select * from 
        (Select distinct Country from #test) a
    cross join
        (Select distinct a.product + '_' + b.product as ProductCombination from #test a
        left join #test b
        on a.product < b.product) b
    where b.ProductCombination is not null
    )
, calculations as ( --count purchasers of combinations, and use this combined with the earlier purchaser counts to generate an unduplicated total purchasers count
    select a.country, a.product + '_' + b.product as ProductCombination
        , cast(count(distinct a.customer)*100.0/(a.totalorders + b.totalorders - count(distinct a.customer)) as decimal(5,0)) as PctOfTotal
    from cte2 a
    inner join cte2 b
    on a.country = b.country 
        and a.customer = b.customer 
        and a.product < b.product
    group by a.country, a.product, b.product, a.totalorders + b.totalorders)

select a.*, isnull(b.PctOfTotal, 0) as PercentOfTotal from combinations a
left join calculations b
on a.country = b.country 
    and a.ProductCombination = b.ProductCombination
order by a.country, a.ProductCombination
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried to run this but unfortunately I can't see the result as the query is still running. It seems quite slow.